# Correct Spacing and Positioning of Stacked Newtonian Derivatives

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have been wanting to use Newtonian derivative notation for my physics homework; however, I wished to stack the dots of the derivatives to produce more compact equations.

[image: Current Equation]

**Question**: How do I shrink the horizontal spacing (between the pairs of two periods) for the collections of three and four dots. Also, how would I move these dots to lie where `\ddot` and `\dot` place them? In particular, what command could I use to shift them to the upper right?

**Current Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\threedots}[1]{
  {
    \mathop{
      \kern\z@#1
    }
    \limits^{
      \vbox to-1.4\ex@{
        \kern-\tw@\ex@
          \hbox{
            \normalfont
            \stackanchor[1pt]{.}{..}
          }
          \vss
        }
      }
    }
  }

\newcommand{\fourdots}[1]{
  {
    \mathop{
      \kern\z@#1
    }
    \limits^{
      \vbox to-1.4\ex@{
        \kern-\tw@\ex@
          \hbox{
            \normalfont
            \stackanchor[1pt]{..}{..}
          }
          \vss
        }
      }
    }
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Dot derivative test.

\[
\fourdots{f} + \threedots{f} + \ddot{f} + \dot{f}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question you can use the standard accents

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ f + \dot{f} + \ddot{f} + \dot{\ddot{f}} + \ddot{\ddot{f}} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If for some reason `amsmath` isn't loaded, the `accents` package has the same effect.